# I want to define variable in CodeIgniter so that it can be accessed in application

Tags: codeigniter

e.g array of constants so that it can be accessed in controllers, views, models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data doesn't change at runtime you can use config

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for globally accessible datas, then session is more than just a storage feature.

Set the session values like this

```
$this->session->set_userdata('item', 'value');
```

And read the values like this

```
$this->session->userdata('item');
```

Comment: This way you dont have to worry about passing the datas from one MVC segment to another.